# Windows Server 2003 - AT command for repeating a scheduled Task

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, at

Is it possible to use the AT command to create a scheduled task that repeats every X minutes? I can use AT to make one that repeats daily/weekly/monthly, but haven't seen a minute/hourly repeat. I can use the task scheduler to create a task, but don't want to create a new account. Any suggestions?

Comment: As TheCleaner said, schtasks is the better option. If you do find yourself forced to use the AT command (as I was when a client insisted on AT) then you could always use the sleep command (or similar) and have the script/batch rerun the required activity. 

In my case I just had it checking for the status of a service and take action on that (customer legacy code issue) and then it would sleep for 10 minutes. A 'temporary' fix while they sorted out their coding issue - 3 years later I found out they were using my 'fix' - code issue still wasn't fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a parameter in the `AT` command to do this for a single command.  You could create a crazy amount of them to suffice (say 24 to have it run every hour every day).

My advice is to stop using `AT` and use the `schtasks` command that replaces it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596

It will let you create a cmd line task that will do what you are wanting:

Comment: Will schtasks command let you create a task that uses the system account?

Comment: sure, just use `/RU SYSTEM`